# How to display the SQL script for a database using SQL script

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio, sql-scripts

I have a local `.mdf` file I use it as a database in my asp.net webforms website, since I don't have Microsoft SQL Server and I have Visual Studio v2015 also I have a connection string here :

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Dark\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ITResco\App_Data\ITResco_DB.mdf";Integrated Security=True
```

So how can I generate its SQL script since I don't have a `Tasks -> GenerateScript` Command

Comment: If you're using a `.mdf` file, **YOU HAVE** SQL Server ..... you **cannot** use an  `.mdf` file without having a SQL Server engine installed.

Comment: i don't have sql server managment application on my pc but i have visual studio which allowes me to make a .mdf file database but it's not full feature of sql server tasks

Comment: Then you might need to *download* a copy of SQL Server Management Studio and install it, so that you get that functionality ....

Comment: damn it i know the answer will be something like that

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, it seems even the wastly improved SQL Server Object Explorer in VS 2015 still doesn't have this "Generate Scripts" capability on the database level......

Comment: SQL Management Studio 2015 is a free/independant application (currently in preview, november). should work for what you need, though not sure why you didn't install it with the SQL install.